# Encryption using Playfair algorithm

Tags: encryption, encoding

how to encrypt using play fair if "i , j" both are in the plaintext? for example Beijing.

Answer (score 1):

There are dialects where other letters are missing. But otherwise you could always substitute `j` with `i` or `y` of course. I mean, nobody is going to mistake `beiiing` or `beiying` with any other word, especially if it is in a location that provides context (e.g. a sentence that clearly talks about a city or at least a location).

Modern ciphers are secure and operate on bits / bytes. In principle any Unicode string can be converted to bytes, resolving the issue. Playfair is not a cipher that should be used anymore; practical issues are kind of moot at this point.